# Cannot removeObserver?

Tags: ios, notifications, observer-pattern

I've began to learn iOS development for a few weeks,but this bug confused me a lot....

I just post 4 different observers in a ViewController:(They have different notificationames)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"notificationame" object:self userInfo:userinfo];
```

Then I want to add & remove 4 different observers in another ViewController,like this:

```
  -(void)viewwillappear{      
 self.localChangeObserver=[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserverForName:@"notificationame" object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) { }];
 }
 -(void)viewwilldisappear{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self.localChangeObserver];
 }
```

But this"removeObserver" turns out to be not working.Each time I show this ViewController ,it add one more observer,(and then I hide this VC,nothing removed).So I got a lot of observers at last.

And, putting them in ViewDidLoad/dealloc also do not work.

But,another 2 Observers just work fine.like this:

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
   }
  - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 }
```

I really don't know what's wrong with my code.Thanks a lot.

Comment: If that's your real code, then the problem is the method names. `viewwilldisappear` should be `viewWillDisappear`. Put an `NSLog` in each method and make sure that it's being called when you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"OBSERVER NAME" object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *aNotification)
    {
        //Write your Notification handler Code
    }];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"OBSERVER NAME" object:nil];
}
```

This code is working fine...!!!

Comment: THanks for your help..But it still not work.It can successfully add Observers,but cannot remove one.     Each time I go into this ViewController the observers become more and more, then every post noticification lead

Comment: then every post noticification make the block being executed again and agian.

Comment: please remove individual observer with its name which you have mention in your questions.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIKeyboardWillHideNotification" object:nil];

Comment: Although this code doesn't work,Your advice really helps me a lot. At last I found that if I use [addObserverForName:..]this always cannot be removed,but if I use [addObserver:self selector:@selector..] it can be removed. I guess it is because the [postNotificationName:] can only work with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"notificationame" object:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,but it still not works...Maybe I should figure out the error in somewhere else.